Port is configured to accept incoming traffic but isnt open
All IPs, Id's etc are from a test environment and will be deleted, so noting is from an actual production environment.
I have an EC2 security group and I opened four ports for incoming traffic:

I have an EC2 instance that utilizes this security group. I created a docker container and ran it on port 8001:
docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped -p 8001:8001 --name tce-docker_container tce-docker

When i tried to access my server via port 8001 in a browser (http://1.2.3.4:8001), I get connection refused.
I go to an open port checker (https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and this is what I get:

As a matter of fact, only ports 80 & 22 are seen as open even though I have opened ports 443 & 8001.
I can access the default port 80 on my EC2 instance in a browser just fine and I can ssh into my instance as well proving ports 80 & 22 are open.
Why are my ports 443 and 8001 not open? Whatelse can I check in AWS to open these (or any other ports)?
Thank you

Do you have a process running on the instance that is actually listening on that port? Is your httpd configured to listen on Port 443?

Suggest you set up Nginx and test that first, it's simple and from there you can move forwards with docker. Make sure you can curl Nginx on port 80 from the instance, then try from outside AWS. If one works, and the other doesn't, that gives you more information for diagnostics. Please try this and report back.

It’s possible that a firewall or security rule on your EC2 instance itself is blocking your traffic. You could try checking if iptables or another firewall is active on the instance, as these could be restricting access despite the settings in the EC2 security group , so modify or disable the firewall rules as needed. If you’re confident that the EC2 security group provides sufficient protection, you might consider disabling iptables(if its already active) to prevent conflicts

Unlikely. A firewall would result in timeouts, connection refused indicates that nothing is listening on the given port.
